# What does "stronger question deletion votes" mean?

Tags: support, privileges, vote-to-delete, trusted-user

From Stack Overflow's [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq), I noticed the additional privilege:

"20000 Vote to delete negatively voted answers and **stronger question deletion votes** "

I want to know, What does "stronger question deletion votes" mean? if someone gained 20000+ rep, What will happen when he votes to delete?

Comment: It means you can vote to delete immediately a question is closed rather than having to wait 2 days.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you look at the [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) for the 20,000 level you will see this sentence:

> Voting to delete questions immediately
>   after they are closed (even if they
>   are new)

This is a stronger delete privilege as 10,000 level users have to wait 2 days after a question is closed before they can vote to delete it.